# How to make VS show different color of the frame when selected?

Tags: windows-8, colors, visual-studio

This has been annoying me since the change to the progressive and "beautiful" look of VS. When I work in another application, VS's frame is grey. Fine. When I select VS, it stays the same grey. This is not "metro" and not "progressive". It's **stupid**!

How can I make the IDE to get a different color when the application is in focus? Preferably to the same theme as the rest of Windows. And no, changing the scheme in Windows **and** in VS to Blue didn't do jack.

Comment: this is done in VS2013. Do you still use VS2012?

Comment: I'm using VS13 and VS15. Time will force us to move to VS15 so the most desirous request would be regarding that version. Is it changeable? How?!

Comment: starting with VS2013 the Windows is gray when it is in background, so you have an issue. Do you use the latest GPU drivers?

Comment: I think so, I do the updates regularly. But just to be clear - the issue is not that it's boring gray when in background. The problem is that it's not indigo when it's active! A window is a window. It should obey the color I pick for the windows!    :)